# Show Multiple models data in one view

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller, view, model

My project is based on Asp.net Mvc i have facing the issue to show multiple model data in one view but didn't show in list or grid view it should be show in Form View style 
i have two modals class Product , BusinessCase

```
public class productViewModel
{
    public string ProductTitle { get; set; }

    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    public string Composition { get; set; }

    public string Requirment { get; set; }
}
```

business case viewModel

```
public class BcaseViewModel
{
    public string ExecutiveSummary { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedBenefits { get; set; }
    public string DisBenefits { get; set; }
    public string Cost { get; set; }
    public string MajorRisks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show these two view model data in one view that is

```
public ActionResult PBView()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new ViewModel that contains your ViewModels and use it.

```
public class customViewModel{
{
    public productViewModel productViewModel {get; set;}
    public BcaseViewModel BcaseViewModel {get; set;}
}
```